# Android not killable background service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, background

I'm writing an Android app and this app has a background service, which does "heavy" work (so with a long working duration). 
I'm running this service as a remote service so the communication is done by AIDL.

So if I close the app (by pressing the back- or homebutton) all threads/handler started by the service will also be killed. Obviously I don't want this to happen because this work has to be finished.

#### Scroll down for my solution

Here are the importend parts from the sourcecode:

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    /*variables and stuff*/
    private final BlockedUserList blockedUserList = new BlockedUserList(this);

    // my AIDL-Interface
    private final ILoginServiceRemote.Stub binder = new ILoginServiceRemote.Stub() {

        // in this method the magic happens and the task will be started
        @Override
        public boolean login(int id, String passwordHash, String dbPasswordHash) throws RemoteException {

            if (!passwordHash.equals(dbPasswordHash)) {
                blockedUserList.add(id);
                return false;
            }
            blockedUserList.remove(id);

            return true;
        }

        // other stuff...
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

MyHandler.java

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {

    /*variables and constructor*/

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        long lastSystemTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.INTENT_ACTION);

        do {

            /*do stuff*/
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), Integer.toString(taskRemainingTime));
            getApplicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

            SystemClock.sleep(MyService.SLEEP_TIME);
        } while (taskRemainingTime > 0);

    }
}
```

MyUser.java

```
public class MyUser {

    /*variables and stuff*/

    private HandlerThread handlerThread;
    private Handler handler;
    private Looper looper;

    public MyUser() {
        // got this from the android docs
        handlerThread = new HandlerThread(Integer.toHexString(id), HandlerThread.NORM_PRIORITY);

        handlerThread.start();
        looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
        handler = new MyHandler(this, looper);
    }

    public void increaseTries() {
        boolean start = false;
        /*
        do fancy stuff and set start to true...
        */
        if (start) {
            // start the "heavy" work
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }
}
```

So why gets my service reseted or what ever if I call unbind in the activity.onDestroy()?

And how can I prevent this? Obviously this is possible because almost every music player runs a background service which continue playing the music even if you kill the app from the recents list. 
I tried "normal" threads, AsyncTask and Timer but get killed if I remove my app from the recents list.

## Edit:

So unforunately there is no way to run a Service infinitely in background. So I have to use a "workaround" to solve this problem.

Here is how I do this:

when Android calls `onUnbind`, I serialize the importend data to JSON and create a hash. Then I write these two strings to the `SharedPrefs`. When the Service gets restarted through `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand`, I read the data from the file parse it into my data objects and continue my work. And also do some error handling if needed.

I have no idea if this is a good solution or just completely stupid but it works.

---

Thanks for helping,

Clemens

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just tested Pandora, the music stopped playing after removing from recents.